# How to mock a class field by using stretchr/testify?

Tags: go

I am using `https://github.com/stretchr/testify` go library to mock class. I'd like to mock a class's field for aws sdk package: `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/apigatewaymanagementapi`.

The code I have is:

```golang
func publishData(ctx context.Context, api *apigatewaymanagementapi.Client) {

   ...
   api.PostToConnection(...)
}
```

I need to mock the `PostToConnection` method. I set up the mock like:

```golang
type MockApi struct {
    apigatewaymanagementapi.Client
    mock.Mock
}

func (m *MockApi) PostToConnection() (*apigatewaymanagementapi.PostToConnectionOutput, error) {
    m.Called()
    return nil, nil
}
```

In my test case,

```golang
api := MockApi{}
api.On("PostToConnection").Return(nil, nil)
```

The mock doesn't work and the code still uses the real `Client`. I think the issue is the mock only mocks the root level method rather than `Client.PostToConnection` method.

How can I mock the method under `Client`?

Comment: Go authors recomended that you should not use test library (https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/TestComments#assert-libraries), make use of Go itself instead of creating a mini-language inside Go. You see it is hard to use their mock, so just write your own mock

Answer (score 0):

Replace *apigatewaymanagementapi.Client with your own interface. For this interface, in tests, you can write an implementation (stub) yourself or use a library to generate it (like https://github.com/golang/mock).

Example:

```
type (
    PublisherClient interface {
        PostToConnection(ctx context.Context, someArgs ... interface{})
    }
)

func publishData(ctx context.Context, api PublisherClient) {
    api.PostToConnection(ctx)
}
```

```
type (
    PublisherClientMock struct {
        Args []interface{}
    }
)

func (c PublisherClientMock) PostToConnection(ctx context.Context, someArgs ... interface{}) {
    c.Args = someArgs
}
```

Comment: if I do that I have to write many interfaces if there are many 3rd party dependencies and generate many stub code?

Comment: If you want to test your code, yes. You say "write" like it's a lot of work. You just copy the method signature into your interfaces, write one line `//go:generate mockgen ...` to generate all mocks, and forget about it.